# Correctly Mocking $resource/ promise service with Jasmine Spy

Tags: mocking, jasmine, angular-promise

I am having trouble mocking and testing my angular app. Given the file below, I am always getting the error **deferred is not defined.**

How can I correctly mock the API with Promise ? and How can I test that the API is indeed running and attach the response to the *$scope.data* variable?

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('controllerOne', [
    '$scope',
    'API',
    function($scope, API) {
        $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.data = API.query(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        };

    }
]);
```

**API Service**

```
angular.module('app').factory('API', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/url/:Id', {
            Id: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

**Controller Spec**

```
describe('app Module', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });
    var mockAPI, q, $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockAPI = {
            query: function() {
                var deferred = q.defer();
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;
        ctrl = $controller('controllerOne', {
            $scope: $scope,
            API: mockAPI
        });
    }));
    it('should query API', function() {
        spyOn(mockAPI, 'query').and.callThrough();
        $scope.init();
        deferred.resolve();
        $scope.$root.$digest();
        expect(mockAPI.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

*If I run the following code, everything works, **but I think it is not right**, as I am initializing the API myself.*

```
it('should query API', function() {
    mockAPI.query();
    expect(mockAPI.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

What and How is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having is due to the scoping of the deferred variable defined in mockAPI query.  It should be scoped at the suite level, so that it can be accessed to resolve in your tests.

Assuming the rest of your code is good, the following would resolved your issue with **deferred is not defined**.

```
describe('app Module', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });
    var mockAPI, deferred, q, $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockAPI = {
            query: function() {
                deferred = q.defer();
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;
        ctrl = $controller('controllerOne', {
            $scope: $scope,
            API: mockAPI
        });
    }));
    it('should query API', function() {
        spyOn(mockAPI, 'query').and.callThrough();
        $scope.init();
        deferred.resolve();
        $scope.$root.$digest();
        expect(mockAPI.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```